# MSBuild to deploy changed files

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

**After the answer I got, I found that I have to give more info on my problem, so I changed my question.**

We are building a web application that is showing maps.
The map can be edited by the users and saved as xml file.
There is a tool (exe application) that can be run from command line which transfer the xml to binary format, and deploy them to the mapping application.
to run that tool is taking few minutes for each map.
I am trying to have an automated build script using MSBuild, that run from our build server (Team City) that will automated this process.

So, what I want is to have the script, check out the maps from source control (TFS) and run that tool.

But because it is slow, I want to find a way to do it only for the files that changed.

So, if an xml didn't change I don't want to run the tool.

Is there a way from MSBuild to find the files that changed from update from source control?

or do you have idea how to do that?
I thought about it, and came up with storing the last modified of xml in a text file, but I don't like this idea.

as I said, I am using 
Source Control: TFS
Build script : MSBuild
Build Server: Team City

Answer (score 0):

MsBuild has built-in functionality to compare the last modified date.  [You'd see this in cases where you specify the Inputs and Outputs on a target, allowing the target to be skipped if the Inputs are older then the Outputs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264087.aspx)...

In your case I'd suggest using the [Copy Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx), setting SkipUnchangedFiles to true.

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(MapFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(DeployPath)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

Comment: I appreciate your input.
And I am trying to find how can I use that.
So, if you have idea, please let me know
My problem is more complex.
I modified my question to explain more my problem.